# SharePoint Forms Fields depend on User

Tags: javascript, jquery

I hope you all are doing good. I have an query regarding SharePoint forms I hope if anyone can help me out.

I want to create a SharePoint form where a member from any department can ask for a leave, there will be many fields in that particular form but a member could only view some , when member send that request to its manager than manager should see some more fields for example Approved or Not Approve with the precious fields fill by the member, then the form will go to the HR and they can now see some additional fields with the previous fields.

Can anyone help me out or either give me a direction that where to look? 
Thank You.

Answer (score 2):

SharePoint does not have security on fields. Trimming the UI based on permissions does **not** lock down the fields.

It is going to be easier if you use the 'Rocket' stages approach.

- Create a List where users can enter Leave Requests
- create a (SPDesigner) Workflow which copies the values to a "Manager" List
- on Manager approval use another Workflow to copy the data to a HR List

If you stay within one Site (Web) you can do it all with SharePoint Designer Workflows

All you need then is custom permissions on the three Lists

Answer (score 0):

Look at security trimming by permission levels. You'll also need to hide fields from the list views, and disallow creating personal views so users can't create their own view to see all of the sensitive information.
http://www.robertkuzma.com/2011/03/security-trimmed-controls-in-sharepoint/
http://maiomardesouki.com/2011/07/23/security-trimmed-controls-in-sharepoint/